# any way to make nested callback code in javascript more readable?

Tags: javascript, node.js, syntax, callback

consider this baby simple piece of code

```
pg.connect( {
    user: 'hhope',
    password: '...',
    port: 5432,
    host: '/var/run/postgresql',
    database: 'phiddler' },
  function( err, client ) {
    client.query(
      "select count(1) as ct from pg_prepared_statements",
      function( err, results ) {
        console.log( 'prepared statement count: '+results.rows[0].ct );
        client.query( {
                    name: 'test2' ,
                    text: "insert into t1( c2 ) values( 'q1')" },
          function( err, result ) {
            console.log( 'inserted t1' );
            client.query(
              "select count(1) as ct from pg_prepared_statements",
               function( err, results ) {
                  console.log( 'prepared statement count: '+results.rows[0].ct );
               } );
           }
        );
      }
    );
  }
);
```

if written procedurally would be

```
pg = new PG(...);
client = new pg.client();
console.log( client.col( "select ..." ) );
client.prepare( 'test2', "insert into t1( c2 ) values( 'q1')" );
console.log( client.col( "select ..." ) );
```

in my mind the latter is far more readable and maintainable.

is there some sort of compromise approach that would make the standard indented callback style more readable?

Comment: Belongs on: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use the [`async`](https://github.com/caolan/async/) library's [`waterfall`](https://github.com/caolan/async/#waterfall) mechanism:

```
var async = require('async');

async.waterfall([
    pg.connect.bind(this, {
        user: 'user', password: 'pass', port: 5432, host: '/somewhere/', database: 'db'
    }),
    function(client, callback) {
        client.query('select * from foo', callback)
    }
], function(err, results) {
    console.log(results);
});
```

The `bind` method added to `Function`s in ES5 is *very* useful in combination with the async library, since often the last argument in the list is a callback, and the earlier values are often known before entering the chain.

Answer (score 0):

The procedural variant isn't really equivalent - I assume its synchronous, whereas the original probably isn't.

If you don't need to close over variables, you can just use named functions. Something like:

```
function f2(){}
function f1() {
    client.query("select count(1) as ct from pg_prepared_statements", f2);
}
pg.connect( {
    user: 'hhope',
    password: '...',
    port: 5432,
    host: '/var/run/postgresql',
    database: 'phiddler' },
    f1
);
```

Comment: The ``connect`` method passes the ``client`` object into its callback, so as written that won't work.

Comment: agree that they're not equivalent, with the latter being synchronous (as you said).  did not put in variable assignment because did not want people addressing whether could be done in one vs two client calls as versus the syntax itself.  agree, can name funcs, but imho worser of two evils.

Answer (score 0):

"Readable" is a matter of opinion, but you could do this:

```
var iter = function(cb) {
   var v = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
   var f = function() {
        var g = v.shift();
        g && g(f);
   };

   f();
};

iter(function(cb) {
        console.log('in f1');
        cb();
     },
     function(cb) {
        console.log('in f2');
        cb();
     });
```